# PHP SimpleXMLElement add child using xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<precompilata xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="730_precompilata.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <proprietario>
        <codiceRegione>604</codiceRegione>
        <codiceAsl>120</codiceAsl>
        <codiceSSA>010011</codiceSSA>
        <cfProprietario>x42Ft28lh/e4WGpFQmpIrmwaXeii0e8k2F/59MHVLoyhSf//ZDrpTWsFFqZXlJgMq9+blw63F2UMy2IchdXBJn8j9AAVPwShVLsWZ9bv4cotqNJHxvBee4Y/O1r1G3MAm2/uH0NL8vgS5mfp11GCVwm1j63fpx+CcL/fjQHiLlk=</cfProprietario>
    </proprietario>

    <documentoSpesa>
        <idSpesa>
            <pIva>98765432104</pIva>
            <dataEmissione>2016-01-01</dataEmissione>
            <numDocumentoFiscale>
                <dispositivo>1</dispositivo>
                <numDocumento>3002</numDocumento>
            </numDocumentoFiscale>
        </idSpesa>
        <dataPagamento>2016-01-01</dataPagamento>
        <flagOperazione>I</flagOperazione>
        <cfCittadino>iKvd9JQntqxPBT2UA/OFfztSNLidocP8Op+NfODzfTdxFWzkcdZrJz5gvCuqv7Dh/r3Cin1ZQMmg/BofIqYCyq2PcC+PJzbvQCocDdl6FrXVXs3W5JhnX7VpWFGCLPYYY2WL+RWKxhfkGqeY8+NCVfQ1lEA15g3W5AabJ15Tthk=</cfCittadino>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AA</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>10.56</importo>
        </voceSpesa>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AD</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>100.50</importo>
        </voceSpesa>
    </documentoSpesa>

    <documentoSpesa>
        <idSpesa>
            <pIva>98765432104</pIva>
            <dataEmissione>2016-01-22</dataEmissione>
            <numDocumentoFiscale>
                <dispositivo>1</dispositivo>
                <numDocumento>1234</numDocumento>
            </numDocumentoFiscale>
        </idSpesa>
        <dataPagamento>2016-01-01</dataPagamento>
        <flagOperazione>I</flagOperazione>
        <cfCittadino>vCuqv7Dh/r3Cin1ZQMmg/BofIqYCyq2PcC+PJzbvQCocDdl6FrXVXs3W5JhnX7VpWFGCLPYYY2WL+RWKxhfkGqeY8+NCVfQ1lEA15g3W5AabJ15Tthk=</cfCittadino>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AA</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>10.56</importo>
        </voceSpesa>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AD</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>100.50</importo>
        </voceSpesa>
    </documentoSpesa>

</precompilata>
```

I have multiple (N) child of `documentoSpesa`.
I need to add another child `voceSpesa` when `documentoSpesa->dataEmissione` and `documentoSpesa->numDocumentoFiscale->numDocumento` already exists.

for example, if I need to add this child inside `documentoSpesa->dataEmissione` = 2016-01-22 and `documentoSpesa->numDocumentoFiscale->numDocumento` = 1234

```
<voceSpesa>
    <tipoSpesa>AD</tipoSpesa>
    <importo>99.50</importo>
</voceSpesa>
```

I don't know if this is the correct approach: (it doesn't works)
`$xml->xpath('/precompilata/documentoSpesa/idSpesa[dataEmissione = "'.$DocDate.'" and ../numDocumentoFiscale/numDocumento/text() = "'.docNum'"] ');`

What I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<precompilata xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="730_precompilata.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <proprietario>
        <codiceRegione>604</codiceRegione>
        <codiceAsl>120</codiceAsl>
        <codiceSSA>010011</codiceSSA>
        <cfProprietario>x42Ft28lh/e4WGpFQmpIrmwaXeii0e8k2F/59MHVLoyhSf//ZDrpTWsFFqZXlJgMq9+blw63F2UMy2IchdXBJn8j9AAVPwShVLsWZ9bv4cotqNJHxvBee4Y/O1r1G3MAm2/uH0NL8vgS5mfp11GCVwm1j63fpx+CcL/fjQHiLlk=</cfProprietario>
    </proprietario>

    <documentoSpesa>
        <idSpesa>
            <pIva>98765432104</pIva>
            <dataEmissione>2016-01-01</dataEmissione>
            <numDocumentoFiscale>
                <dispositivo>1</dispositivo>
                <numDocumento>3002</numDocumento>
            </numDocumentoFiscale>
        </idSpesa>
        <dataPagamento>2016-01-01</dataPagamento>
        <flagOperazione>I</flagOperazione>
        <cfCittadino>iKvd9JQntqxPBT2UA/OFfztSNLidocP8Op+NfODzfTdxFWzkcdZrJz5gvCuqv7Dh/r3Cin1ZQMmg/BofIqYCyq2PcC+PJzbvQCocDdl6FrXVXs3W5JhnX7VpWFGCLPYYY2WL+RWKxhfkGqeY8+NCVfQ1lEA15g3W5AabJ15Tthk=</cfCittadino>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AA</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>10.56</importo>
        </voceSpesa>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AD</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>100.50</importo>
        </voceSpesa>
    </documentoSpesa>

    <documentoSpesa>
        <idSpesa>
            <pIva>98765432104</pIva>
            <dataEmissione>2016-01-22</dataEmissione>
            <numDocumentoFiscale>
                <dispositivo>1</dispositivo>
                <numDocumento>1234</numDocumento>
            </numDocumentoFiscale>
        </idSpesa>
        <dataPagamento>2016-01-01</dataPagamento>
        <flagOperazione>I</flagOperazione>
        <cfCittadino>vCuqv7Dh/r3Cin1ZQMmg/BofIqYCyq2PcC+PJzbvQCocDdl6FrXVXs3W5JhnX7VpWFGCLPYYY2WL+RWKxhfkGqeY8+NCVfQ1lEA15g3W5AabJ15Tthk=</cfCittadino>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AA</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>10.56</importo>
        </voceSpesa>
        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AD</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>100.50</importo>
        </voceSpesa>


        <voceSpesa>
            <tipoSpesa>AD</tipoSpesa>
            <importo>99.50</importo>
        </voceSpesa>


    </documentoSpesa>

</precompilata>
```

This is the code for testing: http://pastebin.com/eaAAdTZ5
and this is the csv file http://simoneseri.com/Anno2016_test.csv (put in the same directory of script)

Comment: Please show a complete PHP script that can be used to reproduce your issue and also show very clearly what you would like the output to be. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I have added pastebin with PHP code and csv file for testing, I hope it help for clarification

Comment: XPath is a query language. You can't modify XML documents with XPath.

Comment: @nwellnhof Yes, I know, but I can find the node with XPath.